# Offline Authentication

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps, angularfire

In an Angular PWA I'm using firebase security rules to restrict access to nearly all of my data to authenticated users. In an auth-guard I check if the user is authenticated and if not, the user is signed in anonymously (`signInAnonymously()`) so I ensure that I have a user-id that I can use to flag objects that the user creates. This flag is necessary so I know if the user is the creator and if he is allowed to delete his own comment.

This all works fine - also when I lose connectivity. But if I close the PWA, enable flight-mode and then open the PWA (without connectivity) - `signInAnonymously` returns an error (because of course the user cannot be signed in on the server). I on the other hand expect to either get the user from `LocalStorage / IndexedDb` returned or that after opening the app the `onAuthStateChanged`-Event fires with the locally stored user.

None of this happens (although I see, that the user is in fact stored in indexeddb by Firebase). [Docs: Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) also state, that

> For a web application, the default behavior is to persist a user's session even after the user closes the browser.

What am I missing? What should I do differently to achieve my goal of:

> The PWA should behave like a native app. If I have no connectivity, as I use `enableIndexedDbPersistence()` for Firestore, the app should load whichever data is in cache and as soon as connectivity is restored, the app should seamlessly use online data.

**Edit:**
This is the code of my `AuthService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private authState: User = null;

    private _isAuthenticated = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
    public isAuthenticated$ = this._isAuthenticated.asObservable();

    public get userId() {
        if (this.authState)
            return this.authState.uid;

        throw "No User-Id!";
    }

    constructor(private fAuth: Auth) {
        onAuthStateChanged(this.fAuth, async (user) => {
            AdminConsoleDialogComponent.addLogLine(`onAuthStateChanged: ${user?.uid}`);

            this.authState = user;
            try {
                if (!this.authState) {
                    this.authState = (await signInAnonymously(this.fAuth)).user;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                AdminConsoleDialogComponent.addLogLine(`onAuthStateChanged Error: ${e}`);
                console.error(e);
            } finally {
                this._isAuthenticated.next(this.authState != null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Output as follows (from `addLogLine`-Calls):

- Open the PWA **with** connectivity:

> onAuthStateChanged: tszjaBTtltVo9XV5B4kHAHnNNt22

- Close/Kill the PWA, go into Flight-Mode and reopen PWA **without** connectivity:

> onAuthStateChanged: undefined
>
> onAuthStateChanged Error: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error).

- Close/Kill the PWA, go out of Flight-Mode and reopen PWA **with** connectivity:

> onAuthStateChanged: undefined
>
> onAuthStateChanged: D54ENbliWVhyYc9izXjFbtzXhUG2

I just realized that I even get a new anonymous user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot pinpoint it exactly but after deleting node_modules/package-lock.json (and with this updating @angular/* packages from `12.2.5` to `15.2.7`) it seems to work fine. There must have been a bugfix recently.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code always calls `signInAnonymously` when the page loads, to sign in the user anonymously. That's actually an anti-pattern, as it means the SDK will call to the server, which explains why your code fails.

The idiomatic way to restore the sign-in state of your user is to use an `onAuthStateChange` listener, as shown in this first code sample from the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Then only when there is no current user, will you want to call `signInAnonymously` (or any other sign-in provider) to sign in for the first time.

---

**Update** 2022-04-04: I tried to reproduce the problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/auth-v9-restore.

When I refresh the preview panel with the little ↻ icon on the right, it reloads the anonymous user for me both on my laptop with the wifi disabled, and on my phone in airplane mode.

[image]

Comment: I've edited my question with some code. I never get a user in `onAuthStateChanged` (if I have no connectivity).

Comment: Did a call `signInAnonymously` complete successfully at least once before you went offline?

Comment: Yes. And it showed the JSON-String of the whole `user`-Object. Then fully closed/killed the app, went into flight mode, opened the app and the `user`-Object shows up `null` (at least the `onAuthStateChanged` got called)

Comment: Hmm... I would have expected that `onAuthStateChanged` would actually fire with the signed-in user in that case, as it's supposed to assume the user stays signed in while offline. I'm not sure why that isn't happening for you. You might want to update your question with the additional information, including how/when you actively sign in, and the log output you get. That way maybe somebody else spots what's going on.

Comment: I tried reproducing this problem unsuccessfully. My repro is a bit simpler than what you have in your question, so it might be worth seeing if this works for you - and if so, what the shortest path is from this to the breaking scenario you posted.

Comment: I tried your Stackblitz (with Chrome on android) and I'm not sure how representative your example is as with my PWA (which is installed) or if I open the PWA in Chrome Browser, I refresh the whole page in airplane mode (not just a part of it). I guess in your example the context (IndexedDb / Serviceworker / Session-Values etc.) for the site stays loaded. I'm also able to **use** the PWA in airplane mode (jump between Page-Components etc.) - just not freshly open it.